# Connection problems when adding Entity Framework but not using it

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework

**UPDATE: 08/02/2016**

It seems that this problem occurs only if the console application runs a lot times on a machine. It seems the machine/server is blocking access to the database if there is multiple number of requets

***NOTE :*** I have removed the for loop from the example, since it gave an wrong impression to people reading the code.

I have a simple connection code

```
            string connectionString = "connection string to database";
            using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                conn.Open();
                using (var trans = conn.BeginTransaction())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Begun transaction");
                }
            }
```

I added that code and ran from the IDE and all was fine, it connected to the database. I ran the resulting command line exe and again all was fine.

I went to Nuget and installed the Entity Framework and ran the same code again and it ran fine from the IDE. Ran the resulting application via command line and I got this strange error

> {"A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
>   Specified)"}
>
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo,
>   SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout,
>   Int64 timerExpire, Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean
>   integratedSecurity, Boolean withFailover)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo
>   serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword,
>   Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean
>   withFailover)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo
>   serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword,
>   Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions,
>   SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer
>   timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential
>   credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword,
>   Boolean redirectedUserInstance)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity
>   identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential
>   credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString
>   newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString
>   userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions
>   options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo,
>   DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection,
>   DbConnectionOptions userOptions)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal&
>   connection)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
>   TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
>   TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   retry)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   retry)    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()    at
>   ConnectionTest.Program.Main(String[] args) in
>   c:\Users\vramanathan\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\ConnectionTest\ConnectionTest\Program.cs:line 20

The error seems to be when opening a connection. I can confirm that EF was just added to the project and not used in any of the code. The app.config for this project looks like this

```
<configuration>
<configSections>
<!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
<section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
</configSections>
 <startup>
  <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
   </startup>
 <entityFramework>
   <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
     <parameters>
       <parameter value="v11.0" />
    </parameters>
   </defaultConnectionFactory>
   <providers>
     <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
 </entityFramework>
     </configuration>
```

I am not sure what I am missing. When I remove EF from the project using Nuget, the same error is coming up. It gets resolved when I reboot the machine.

Does EF automatically inject itself when trying to connect to the db even I have not invoked it ?

Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: ". The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. "

Comment: @MitchWheat the remote instance does allow remote connections. When the same code is executed within IDE, the code executes without issues.

Answer (score 0):

Try opening the connection only once outside of the loop. It is not good practice to open a connection several times in a loop. It is resource intensive. Just reuse the already open connection in your loop. Hope this helps.

Comment: this is not production code and was written only for testing the connection part. And the code is not connecting to the database the first time around.